# get values from table only for a specific day in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, between

i can't get the value inside my database for a specific date

sample values:

```
$from= 12/15/2012 $to= 12/15/2012
$from= 12/16/2012 $to= 12/16/2012
$from= 12/17/2012 $to= 12/17/2012
```

php script:

```
$query=" select * from call where (date_time BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to') ORDER BY date_time DESC";
```

the value on my table which i'm getting my dates from has time in it

ex values on my data base:

```
12/15/2012 2:51
12/15/2012 2:21
12/15/2012 2:55
12/15/2012 3:12
12/16/2012 2:51
12/16/2012 2:21
12/17/2012 2:55
12/17/2012 3:12
```

when i search for `from 12/15/2012 to 12/15/2012`
it does not display the values for

```
12/15/2012
```

but if i search for

from `12/15/2012 to 12/16/2012`

it displays not only the values for 
12/15/2012 but also for 12/16/2012

what should i do so that i can enclose all the values only for that specific date?

Comment: I would suggest storing your dates as timestamps so that they are much easier to search and manipulate.

Comment: Are you sure? Is not possible.

Comment: use `select * from dates where date1 <= date2`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should store your time values in a [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) (or possibly `TIMESTAMP`) column.  Then follow the answers given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063042/timestamp-interval).

However, if you *really* insist on doing this with strings, you could always use a [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM `call` WHERE date_time LIKE '12/15/2012 %'
```

([demo on sqlize.com](http://www.sqlize.com/0pGU3My8Lo))

Of course, this only works for finding all records for a single day (or, with appropriate modification, for a single hour / minute / month / year / etc.).  If you need more complicated selection criteria, I'd strongly suggest switching to a real `DATETIME` column.

Comment: I think he want the query for `to and from` For both, exact similar dates and dates in between . `Like` will do for only exact similar dates. So i guess he can get his results by using `<= ` operator (using string to date function)

Comment: @softgenic: Maybe, and if so, he really should use a `DATETIME` column (or, at the very least, [ISO-style date formatting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).  But all his examples show the single days.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are storing dates as datetime field, you should convert data to `Date` type.

When you write:

```
$from= 12/15/2012
```

PHP do a division: 12 / 15 and then ( 12 / 15 ) / 2012

An approach will be declare `$from` as string and cast to date in query:

```
$from= '12/15/2012'
...
"select * from call where (date_time BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$from', '%m/%d/%Y') ..."
```

The right query for a **index friendly** plan is:

```
select * 
from   `call` 
where  date_time >= STR_TO_DATE('$from', '%m/%d/%Y') and 
       date_time < date_add( STR_TO_DATE('$to', '%m/%d/%Y'), interval 1 day)
```

[See it in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15de1/1/0)

Comment: Thats what i was talking about :)