# How to display records for specific date in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have to display records for specific date.Below Code i tried.I am getting output "0 Results";

```
   $startDate=$_POST['startDate'];//date in format(d-m-y)
       $endDate=$_POST['endDate'];//date in format(d-m-y)

     include("../db/connection.php") ;

     $sql ="SELECT *FROM Emp WHERE empDate BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["Id"]. " - Name: " . $row["First_name"]. " " . $row["Last_name"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
}
```

I have records in my database like this

```
2016-10-03 2:51:35
2016-10-03 2:53:25
2016-10-04 3:52:30
2016-10-04 4:15:55
```

I founded question on stackoverflow [get values from table only for a specific day in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086096/get-values-from-table-only-for-a-specific-day-in-mysql) but that query is not working for me.Would you help me in this?

Comment: `$sql ="SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE empDate BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'";` u need to add single quotes around date value

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.devpro, I tried that also but still i am getting 0 results

Comment: <?php
$startDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['startDate'])); 
$endDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['endDate'])); 
?>

Comment: make sure that the data type of empDate  is date or datetime in database @NarendraVerma

Comment: echo $sql........

Comment: Mr.Strawberry, echo $sql result is SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE empDate BETWEEN '2016-10-03' AND '2016-10-04'

Comment: And i have records like this 2016-10-03 2:51:35  2016-10-04 2:51:35 in my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you must need to change Date Format as "Y-M-D" by using `strtotime()`:

```
<?php
$startDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($_POST['startDate'])); // will return data something like 2016-10-05 00:00:00
$endDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($_POST['endDate'])); // will return data something like 2016-10-05 00:00:00
?>
```

Than you need to use single quote around Date value in your SQL Statement:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE empDate BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'";
```

According to your question, you have date value as:

```
2016-10-03 2:51:35
2016-10-03 2:53:25
2016-10-04 3:52:30
2016-10-04 4:15:55
```

In your database, so you must need to use DATE in "Y-M-D" format.

---

*Also note that, your code is open for SQL Injection, you must need to prevent your code with SQL Injection and this reference will help you: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*

---

**Update:**

In your case, if you are not getting `H:i:s` from `$_POST` input than you can use like that:

```
<?php
$startDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['startDate']));
$endDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['endDate']));
$sql ="SELECT * FROM Emp 
    WHERE empDate 
    BETWEEN '$startDate 00:00:00' AND '$endDate 23:59:59'";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.devpro, $startDate,$endDate results are showing in 2016-10-05 format,

Comment: u need this format, i have updated my answer: `Y-m-d H:i:s` @NarendraVerma

Comment: i tried your sql query it displayin only starDate records

Comment: can u please share the result of `print_r($_POST)` ?? @NarendraVerma

Comment: I am getting output in array format...Array ( [startDate] => 03-10-2016 [endDate] => 04-10-2016 [submit] => Export ) 2016-10-032016-10-04id: 1 - Name: Nivas Jadhav
id: 2 - Name: Javandal Ravindra

Comment: And this records are  2016-10-03

Comment: Yup,That's cool!!!! Your update code is working for me now...Thanks for help Mr.devpro

Comment: @NarendraVerma: glad to help u dont forgot to accept the answer this will help to others.

Answer (score 0):

Convert date into Standard Format and execute the query

```
$startDate=Date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startDate));
$endDate=Date('Y-m-d',strtotime($endDate));
```

After try this query

```
SELECT *FROM Emp WHERE DATE(empDate) BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
```